# Package installation not working with pip and Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to instal a module using pip in python and the package isn't available after a successful install.

```
  776  sudo -H pip3 install sqlparse
  777  sqlparse
```

The error message is: `zsh: command not found: sqlparse`

Why would this be? Is there an issue with the path?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the command is sqlformat